# How to calculate different permutations with multiple options?

Tags: permutations

I'm not a mathematician (although I do enjoy math). I'm a photographer. A wedding photographer to be exact. I'm currently re-vamping my album pricing and I want to show my clients just how customizable my albums are by giving them a number of possible variations.

So here are the details:

I offer two different types of products: albums and book, but every customization option below can be used on an album and a book.

Some options are multiple choice, but mutually exclusive, like a cover material - you can only have one cover material chosen. Some are binary - you either order a dust jacket or you don't. And some are able to be used in combination with others. I will try to explain all of this.

```
Type of book (binary): album or book

Cover material (mutually exclusive): 58 options

Cover debossing (mutually exclusive): 13 options

Dust jacket (binary)

Cameo Window (binary)

Album mini (mutually exclusive): yes, no, multiple copies

Storage Box (mutually exclusive): None or 5 options
```

I'd love to understand the math a bit, but I'm mostly after the answer. Also, just so you know I'm not asking for help with my homework, here is my website: www.meandhimphoto.com :-)

Comment: Do you just want to know how many products, in total, are possible? If so, it is 2*58*13*2*2*3*6.

Comment: "*I'd love to understand the math a bit*"... This follows from a concept called [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) which when applied to combinatorics can be paraphrased to say *if you can describe each outcome uniquely via a sequence of choices where the number of choices at each step doesn't depend on previously made choices, then the total number of outcomes is the product of the number of choices at each step*.

Comment: @jmoravitz thank you! +1 internets to you as well! 